# mysql is not saving greek/international characters

Tags: mysql, hibernate, character-encoding

I know this has been questioned and answered already, but I am still now able to figure it out.
I have two servers, prod and dev. On dev, I can see the international and greek letters getting saved. Though in prod, they are saved as "?". I checked the @@character_set_database, @@collation_database and it is utf8/utf8_unicode_ci for both. What could be causing it?

Mysql version is 5.6 in prod and 5.7 in dev

following is the schema of one of the table (which is same in dev and prod)
[image]

Comment: Whats your table schema look like? and an example query inserting these characters?

Comment: I am using hibernate and it is same code for prod and dev. I will update the question with example insert

Comment: I am using hibernate, so the insert is through that

Comment: one more thing, if I make dump the mysql data from prod and load in dev, I can see it is saving the international characters.

Comment: I'd double-check the connection DSN. One of the JDBC connection parameters set the character set. You need to make sure that's utf8.

Comment: By the way, this is not related to your question (maybe), but you should always use the same version of software dependencies in dev and prod. You never know what differences there are. Feature differences or even bugfixes can change behavior.

Comment: aah, i see one difference. In dev in jdbc connection parameter, I have  "&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8" which is missing in prod.

Comment: @BillKarwin, can you put it as the answer, I will accept it. This seems to be the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check the connection DSN. One of the JDBC connection parameters is `characterEncoding`. You need to make sure that's set to utf8.

You confirmed this in a comment above.

Wherever possible, make your code, your configuration, and your software dependencies (like the version of MySQL) the same between dev and prod. It makes extra work for you to troubleshoot differences like this, and it's avoidable!